# Migration issue in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, migration

I am willing to create a new model i.e a new table for my application. I have already a table existing for my application and I want to create a new one. But I am facing problem when running `rake db:migrate` command after executing the following command for creating a new table.

`rails g model information age:string name:string`

while running `rake db:migrate` command the system is showing the following error message:

**don't know how to build task db:migrate**

And no table is created ultimately. I am using **Postgresql**.

A migration is generated as :

```
class CreateInformation < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
  create_table :information do |t|
   t.string :age
   t.string :name

   t.timestamps null: false
  end
 end
end
```

And no change in the `schema.rb` file .

Comment: Are you trying to create a model or a migration?

Comment: Is Rails properly installed, and are you running `rake` from app directory?

Comment: I am trying to create a model.Actually I need to create a new table.Thats why I am trying to generate a new model. After that I ran rake db:migrate command because I can not see any table created newly in my pgadmin

Comment: yes definitely ,,,rails is installed properly because I have run another application

Comment: Post the output of rake db:migrate.Run 'rake -T' to see the tasks.

Comment: show me error please

Comment: I have done with this. I stopped the server totally and  next time ran it and it was executed in fine manner

Comment: rake --describe db:migrate use this command  and see what happen and let me know

Answer (score 0):

To create a model, you need to write `model` after `rails g`.
Make sure you're inside your rails app folder. If you have an existing table with the same name you might want to get rid of it first by dropping it.. Then create again.

```
rails g model Information age name
#age and name will be string by default, so you can omit writing string
```

Comment: sorry I have run it correctly . But here it is an editing mistake.

Comment: Do you have an existing table with the name `informations`?

Comment: Do you see `db:migrate` when you run `rake -T` in your console, inside your rails application directory?

Comment: yeah,, I have seen the trace

Comment: Cool. Then I guess that's okay. You may want to delete your `Gemfile.lock` file and run bundle install to create again. Let me know if that helps?

Comment: No...It is now working fine though I don't know the reason. I deleted the model totally and then recreated it once again.

Answer (score 0):

I Don't think the command you are using matches any rails command generator

```
rails g information age:string name:string
```

if you are generating model it should be

```
rails g model Information age:string name:string
```

I should be capital(read [Rails Conventions](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#convention-over-configuration-in-active-record)=))
and if you are trying to create a migration then it should be

```
rails g migration information age:string name:string
```

and then you run **rake db:migrate** to make it run.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running rails5? You error is this:

> don't know how to build task db:migrate

For rails 5 there is no rake tasks (changed to rails) You should do

```
bin/rails db:migrate
```